# Walter Malone's "The World is My Home"

Tags: poetry, wording-choice, interpretation, walter-malone

Walter Malone's poem ["The World is My Home"](https://allpoetry.com/The-World-is-my-Home) is, on the face of it, openly a plea for humanity to come together as one united brotherhood rather than engage in disputes and wars:

> Travel to East, I wander to West:
> Each land that I see is dear to my breast.
> I greet the green hills as I float down the Rhine,
> The vineyards of France I love as if mine.
> With rapture the castles of England I see,
> And Switzerland's peaks are old friends to me;
> A freeman of Athens, a tribune of Rome,
> All men are my brothers, the world is my home.
>
> Let Sultans and Czars make war if they will,
> But let their own blood on the battlefield spill;
> For none but the Fool will lift up his arm
> To murder the man who has done him no harm.
> Let the bigot cry out for a bloody crusade,
> To pierce heathen hearts with the sanctified blade;
> From mosque of the Nile to Saint Peter's dome
> All men are my brothers, the world is my home.
>
> Wherever we meet, on sea or on sod,
> We are brethren of Christ, we are children of God.
> They may prattle of Codes, or prate of their Creeds--
> I care not for these, but for brotherly deeds.
> They may boast of their Church, their Clique or their Clan--
> I but yearn for the touch of a true fellowman.
> So my heart still repeats, wherever I roam,
> All men are my brothers, the world is my home.

I'm seeking a more detailed analysis/interpretation of this poem, its literary devices and what it may be saying on a deeper level. For example, addressing questions such as the following.

What countries, religions, or cultures (if any) are being indicated by "Codes", "Creeds", "Church", "Clique", "Clan", and why the constant C-alliteration? Why are these words capitalised, and also "Fool" in the second stanza, but no others except proper nouns and others that are commonly capitalised? Is there any significance to the differing choice of words "Travel" and "wander" for east and west? Why are almost all the places mentioned in Europe, and why does the poem say "We are brethren of Christ" while speaking of uniting the world from all different cultures and beliefs? (Is it more Eurocentric than its main message suggests?) Is there any significance to choices of words such as "freeman" and "tribune" (choosing specific types of people from Athenian and Roman society?) and "Sultans" and "Czars" (from which parts of the world?)?